# Question about statement on p. 21 of Dieudonné's Infinitesimal Calculus

Tags: analysis

On p. 21, Dieudonné states that: "... if $f$ is a continuous real function in a
bounded closed interval $I$, there is a smallest root and a largest root of the
equation $f(x)=0$ in $I$."

I haven't been able to convince myself of this basic
statement. I keep thinking of counterexamples that have only one root, or no
roots, that qualify. Please straighten me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $R \subset I$ be the set of roots for $f$. Then because $f$ is continuous, $R$ is closed. Since $I$ bounded, $R$ is compact. In particular, it contains its infimum (which will be the smallest root of f in $I$) and supremum (largest root).

Is it clear?

If $f$ has no roots then $R = \emptyset$, but in that case containing any root of $f$ is a tautology. If $f$ has one root, then the root is both the smallest and largest.

Comment: I posted a comment and then saw your edit to add the bit about tautology. I had a feeling that was going to be it, but nice to have it confirmed by someone better informed. Thank you!

Comment: Now I just have to convince myself that, if there are two roots in $f(x)$, then the inf will be the smallest root and sup the largest root. That the inf and sup are the min and max on the bounded closed interval is intuitive for a real continuous $f$, but that they'd be the smallest and largest roots I have to think about. I guess that is another question though. As an aside, by this point of the book notions of compactness and other topological ideas haven't been touched nor has the boundedness of $f$, only its domain, but those ideas start in the subsequent section.

Comment: @Joe If you have a bounded, closet set $C$, then the infimum is equal to the minimum. This is because there is a sequence of points in $C$ converging to the infimum, by definition. Then because $C$ is closed, it will contain this limit point. So inf = min in this case. Min = smallest root. This is only happening for on the interval$I$.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that is sort of a restatement of my previous comment, however, why must the min or max be a root, that is my question. A root is the $x$ where $f$ vanishes, i.e., where $f(x)=0$, not necessarily where there is a min or max. I must have a wrong understanding of root. To have two roots in a bounded closed interval $f$ must change sign twice, but it needn't do that at the min or max, correct?

Comment: @Joe No, you are misunderstanding. The max and min here refer to the maximum and minimum points in the set R, which is the set of roots of f. This has nothing to do with the maxima or minima of f. Your definition of root is correct.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks. Mixing domain and range, sorry about that. Thanks for hanging in there.

Comment: @Joe No problem. :)